# Rollup with CommonJS module exporting an unnamed function as the module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, commonjs, rollupjs

I have a CommonJS module, called `inner.js`, that defines a function and then exports that function as the entire module:

```
// inner.js, a legacy CommonJS module
var foo = function() { return 42; };
module.exports = foo;
```

In Node, I can readily verify this works as-is.

```
> var inner = require('./inner.js');
> inner() // prints 42
```

But that’s a legacy module that I’d like to use from a ES6 module, called `outer.js`:

```
// outer.js, an ES6 module
import * as inner from "./inner.js";
export function bar() { return inner(); }
```

I see that [`rollup-plugin-commonjs`](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-commonjs) is commonly used in these situations but I can’t get it to work when the CommonJS `inner.js` module exports a function as the whole module. If, after running rollup and dumping the result to `loadme.js`, I try to run load the ES6 outer module and try to call the function originally defined in the inner CommonJS module, I get an error:

```
> var outer = require('./loadme.js')
undefined
> outer.bar()
TypeError: inner$2 is not a function
    at Object.bar (/.../so-rollup-question/loadme.js:27:25)
```

I think I’m just failing to load the CommonJS module correctly, in such a way that the module itself functions as a function. I’m not familiar enough with UMD to get anything meaningful out of inspecting the rollup-output.

The rest of this post is about a minimum example.

---

Here’s my very simple `index.js`:

```
// index.js
export {bar} from "./outer.js";
```

which is read by my rollup config:

```
// rollup.config.js
import npm from "rollup-plugin-node-resolve";
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';

export default {
  entry : "index.js",
  format : "umd",
  moduleName : "sphereModule",
  plugins : [ npm({jsnext : true}), commonjs() ],
  dest : "loadme.js"
};
```

I have a [complete clonable repository](https://gist.github.com/fasiha/5b8fd76623107615db52d014ff7fc752) demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Why are you doing `import * as inner from "./inner.js";` if `inner.js` is only exporting the function? Did you try `import inner from "./inner.js";` ?

Comment: @FelixKling Although I tried many different permutations of things that, to my ignoramus noobish mind, might have helped, I did not try that very simple and obvious one. Thank you. If you’d be so kind as to post an answer, I will gladly & gratefully accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assigning directly to `module.exports` is basically equivalent to having a default export. Hence importing the module as follows should work:

```
import inner from "./inner.js";
```